# Can you do a cross-reference on a web page using only HTML and CSS, and no scripting or programming?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am still learning HTML and CSS and do not know any scripting or programming languages.  I need to refer to an image, table, or a heading in the body of my web page such as, "See Table 6," or "Refer to the images in [text of heading 2]" where the table number or the text of heading 2 might change.  The cross-reference would be a link to that spot on the page.

I used to know how to link to an area on a web page, but cannot figure out how to make the text of the link change if the heading or caption changes.

Here's the HTML.  I have an H4 which is an in-line heading, and a link farther down that goes to the H4.  I think.

```
<div>
<h4 id="Item1">This is an inline heading.</h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;This is the default browser font and font-size because no font is specified.  This is text inside a div.
</div>
<ul>
    <li style="list-style:square url(images/pentpurple.png");">Text for first bullet.</li>
    <li>More text.</li>
</ul>

<ol>
    <li>Text for number one.</li>
    <li>More text.</li>
</ol>

<p>This is a link to <a href id="#Item1">the in-line heading</a> on this web page and this is <a href="https://facebook.com">an outside link</a>.</p>
```

Comment: _"but cannot figure out how to make the text of the link change if the heading or caption changes"_ - This is impossible with just HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Turnip is probably right, but it might be possible to do something similar using attribute value selectors. Please provide a URL for a demo of your page, or add example HTML to your question.

Comment: @Foo Bar, I have added the HTML code per your request.  I'm not sure what you mean by "attribute value selectors."